# When will Runnable.toString() have the possibility to return a duplicate String?

Tags: java, runnable

When will this.toString() possibly return a duplicate String?

```
public static void main(java.lang.String s[]) {
    for(int i=0;i<155000;i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(this.toString());
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean how many threads do you need so that the same output will be provided by two different Threads?

Comment: @blalasaadri yup. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thomas' answer is right in that `Object`'s default `toString()` method will be called which produces different `String`s for different objects.

One thing to note here. `Object.toString()` returns:

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

It includes `Object.hashCode()`. The Javadoc of [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) states:

> ...the hashCode method defined by class `Object` does return **distinct integers for distinct objects**...

The key is that `hashCode()` will be different for **distinct** objects. Since your code does not store the created `Runnable`s, once the `Thread`s are done, they will be garbage collected. Once an object is removed from memory, another `Object` may take its place in memory and it is possible that a new `Runnable` will provide the same hashcode that was returned by a previous `Runnable` which is now **ceased** to exist.

So theoretically it is possible that you will see the same `String` printed indeterministically (although the chances are very slim).

Comment: 1+ you're right, I didn't think of garbage collection and address reuse. @b16db0 if you want to accept an answer, I'd vote for this one. :)

Comment: @Thomas Good thing you confirmed. I was thinking of accepting his answer also. :)

Comment: Assuming the main thread will run indefinitely (infinite `for` loop here) will the GC collect those dead objects while there is an ongoing object allocation (`new Thread(...)`)?

Comment: Obviously they will be GC-ed. If they wouldn't, out of memory error would occur. It is JVM implementation dependent, but if memory usage nears the max limit, you're application is likely to slow down due to increased garbage collecting and memory rearranging.

Comment: You can also test it easily. A `Thread` requires a minimum of 100 bytes (just to account its non-static fields). Run your loop and you will see it does not stop even when iteration `i*100 byte > max memory` which means dead threads must have been removed (else `OutOfMemoryError` or execution "freeze" would have happened).

Answer (score 4):

Since `toString()` by default just returns the class and object id, in your case there should never be duplicates. You're basically creating 155k different anonymous instances of `Runnable` (and `Thread` as well).

Comment: +1 @icza but the `toString()` that is called is that of the `Runnable`, not that of the `Thread`

Answer (score 2):

From the doc : The `toString()` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The `toString()` method you are using is of `Object` class. And as you can see, it involves hashCode, hence it will never print duplicate values,provided that, all the instances of your previous `Runnable` are still **IN** memory.